# Overloading + operator in class

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I am writing a time of day project and part of it is supposed to overload the + operator to add two time objects and return another object as the result. I can't seem to get this down. We have to use a test bed to test it out.

This is what I have for the overload function

```
Time Time::operator +(const Time & that){
Time temp(*this);
*this =(hour, minute);
temp = add(that.hour, that.minute);
return temp;
}
```

This is the test I run

```
Time t24 = (1,1);
Time t25 = (1,1);
t24+t25;
if(t24.getMinute()== 2 && 
   t24.getHour()== 2 )
   good++;
else {  
  Memo1->AppendText(wxString("+ operator fails object. \n"));
  bad++;
}
```

Comment: O sorry about that C++

Comment: Does this even compile?

Comment: `+` operator is supposed to be used in an expression, like `t3 = t24 + t25;` Writing `2 + 3;` doesn't mean much either. Operator that mutates the state of the left operand is `+=`.

Comment: What is this supposed to be?? : `Time t25 = (1,1)` I can almost guarantee this is *not* doing what you think it is, particularly if `Time` supports construction or assignment from `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd overload binary operators like +, -, etc. as free functions (possibly `friend` of `Time` class, if you need to access private `Time` data from these overloads):

```
Time operator+(const Time& lhs, const Time& rhs) {
    ... build a new Time adding lhs and rhs time values
    return Time(hewHour, newMinute);
}
```